# Migrating django-polymorphic models with changed class hierarchy

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south, polymorphism

We use polymorphic models with django-polymorphic.

Recently we changed the hierarchy of these models, from this:

```
class A(PolymorphicModel):
    # foo
class B(A):
    # bar
class C(A):
    # baz
```

to this:

```
class A(PolymorphicModel):
    # foo
class B(A):
    # bar
class C(B):  # C became a subclass of B.
    # baz
```

All fields in B have a default value, so in theory, there is a smooth way to migrate the existing data to the new schema. It needs to create rows in table B, and re-appropriate the baseclass column of table C.

However, South demands a one-off value for C.b_id (and also one for C.a_id, for the backwards migration).

I realize South is not aware of django-polymorphic. Also, django-polymorphic comes in the way when I want to "just add a row in B" in a datamigration.

What would be the most elegant hack to migrate the data in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found was this:

1. Schema migration: add model C_temp that has the same fields as C, but is derived from B.
2. Data migration: copy all data from C to C_temp.

   For each object in C, create a new C_temp by copying all fields, including id. Supply default values for the fields in B.

   This will add the new row in B and connect it with the existing rows in A.
3. Schema migration: delete C.
4. Schema migration: rename C_temp to C.